# Removing watermark stamped from 3rd party application by iText

Tags: pdf, itext, itext7

To give you the context, I am trying to remove a watermark from a pdf generated by some 3rd party application. I am trying to write a utility with iText7 which will detect such watermark and remove it.

Here is the pdf file sample https://easyupload.io/54zhzs. The highlighted watermark text I am trying to remove.

[image]

I was first thinking that it could be added as annotation,but I receive `annots` as null.Had there been annots collection I could have inspected and remove this annotation. This works well when we stamp annotaion with iText itself but here is not that case.

```
 PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(filePath), new PdfWriter(destinationfile));
 for (var i = 1; i <= pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages(); i++)
 {
    PdfDictionary pageDict = pdfDoc.GetPage(i).GetPdfObject();
    PdfArray annots = pageDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.Annots);
    if (annots != null)          
    {
           for (int j = 0; j < annots.Size(); j++)
           {
                 PdfDictionary annotation = annots.GetAsDictionary(j); 
                 if (PdfName.Watermark.Equals(annotation.GetAsName(PdfName.Subtype)))
                 {
                     annotation.Clear();
                 }                        
           }
     }
  }
 pdfDoc.Close();
```

Next, in the second approach I tried to acquire the `PdfObject` like this, but I am clueless here how to identify the correct object which I want to delete.

```
PdfDictionary pageDict = pdfDoc.GetFirstPage().GetPdfObject();
PdfArray fields = pageDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.Fields);
PdfDictionary resources = pageDict.GetAsDictionary(PdfName.Resources);
PdfArray xObjects = resources.GetAsArray(PdfName.ProcSet);
foreach (PdfObject obj in xObjects)
{
   // not sure what to do from here
}
```

This is the debug result what I get. I think in the last ProcSet this watermark is an image layer, but I am not sure what to identify that.

[image]
Am I on right track or is there any other solutions?

Comment: Unfortunately that third party application does not put the mark into a separate object, it is part of the page content stream. Furthermore, the text is not drawn as *text* but as *vector graphics* (filled paths) which is why you cannot select it as text. These facts make it unclear how best to recognize the mark. In your example file it is the first thing drawn and it is marked as **Pagination** **Header** **Artifact**. It is feasible to remove  each path filling operation from the start of the stream or the **Pagination** **Header** **Artifact**, but how representative is this?

Comment: I.e. can you verify (by checking more, less empty example PDFs) whether the path filling operations to remove always are those at the start of the content stream? Or always all those in the **Pagination** **Header** **Artifact**?